# Как найти значения ячеек с жирным шрифтом?

Tags: excel

Нужно выбрать значения ячеек для копирования на другой лист документа, привязавшись к ячейке с жирным шрифтом. На одном сайте нашел такую формулу: `=ЕЖИРНЫЙ(А2)`, но у меня в excel нет такой формулы. Как можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ЕЖИРНЫЙ` - похоже, это имя пользовательской функции, которой у Вас нет. Нужно обрабатывать макросом - в цикле идти по строкам. Определить "жирность" шрифта в ячейке - `Cells(i,1).Font.Bold = True`

Comment: На том же сайте, внизу - функция на VBA, которая возвращает значение `ЯЧЕЙКА.Font.Bold`

Comment: Если формулами: можно цепляться за другие ячейки: название (Телефон, Часы, Сайт), ссылку (www или http), телефон (+ слева)

Comment: Спасибо всем. Но я пока не умею пользоваться VBA. А другие поля (телефон, часы работы и сайт) есть не у всех данных, поэтому остается только привязка к жирному тексту.

Comment: Это разовое действие? если да, то можно отформатировать столбец, выбрав жирные текст и поставить цвет фона. Потом сделать фильтр по цвету фона отобрав только жирные строки. Если не разовое то тут только на vba писать функцию

Comment: Да, мне уже подсказали как написать функцию. Все получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросок.

```
Sub test_()
    Dim aData(), rRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet ' лист с исходными данными'
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' последняя строка с данными'
        Set rRng = .Range("A1:A" & i).Value ' диапазон в переменную, для отслеживания форматирования'
    End With
    
    aData = rRng.Value ' для ускорения чтения данные заносим в массив'
    ReDim aRes(1 To i, 1 To 6) ' 6 - количество столбцов (количество нужных данных из одного блока данных)'
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
        If rRng(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
            k = k + 1 ' номер записи в массиве выгрузки'
            aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 1)
            ' здесь получить другие данные блока'
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Worksheets("2") ' лист для выгрузки результата'
    Worksheets("2").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aRes), UBound(aRes, 2)).Value = aRes
    Set rRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Т.к. "*другие поля (телефон, часы работы и сайт) есть не у всех данных*", то  для получения других данных из блока нужно отслеживать наполнение блока.

Если нужно получить только жирные заголовки блоков, то массив выгрузки можно ограничить одним столбцом.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно написать функцию для формулы на VBA.

```
Function ЕЖИРНЫЙ(ЯЧЕЙКА As Range) As Boolean
  ЕЖИРНЫЙ = ЯЧЕЙКА.Font.Bold
End Function
```

И можно использовать: =ЕЖИРНЫЙ(А2)